# highcharts behaves odd when showing two charts in jquery collapse

Tags: jquery-ui, highcharts

I followed [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/DkHyd/) to achieve an effect like jQueryUI collapse but it could expand any number of regions.

Then, I used highcharts to render two charts in two of the regions. But only the second chart could show correctly while the first chart couldn't. I set the width and height of the region that the first chart renders to but got the same.

I have wrote two javascript functions to control rendering the two charts separately.
It's strange enough that if I commented out the second function that rendered the second chart , the first chart could show correctly.

Please give me some tips on how to resolve the problem.

The html file like this:

```
<div id="notaccordion">
<h3>first chart<h3>
<div id="firstchart"></div>
<h3>second chart</h3>
<div id="secondchart"></div>
</div>
```

The two javascript functions like this:

```
function render_one() {
   ...
   // set the variable 'renderTo' to "firstchart"
   ...
}

function render_two() {
   ...
   // set the variable 'renderTo' to "secondchart"
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post a working example? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The data that highcharts needs is got through ajax and the data is stored locally……

Comment: the data itself isn't relevant to your problem though, so just use whatever test data is fine.

Comment: I think this may be related: http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. If there are two js functions and each has a higcharts object that renders to differnt region, will they collide if they are all executed?

Comment: I commented out one of the js function that rendered a chart, and the chart which couldn't show correctly when the two js functions being executed could show without error.